# Jenkins error while polling TFS - Unable to perform the get operation because it is writable

Tags: c#, jenkins, version-control, tfs, polling

I am using TFS as version control system and trying to Poll it using Jenkins for continuous integration. I have polled few projects successfully, but while polling a (Delphi, C#) project which on the first attempt happened successfully but now if doing some change to the code and polling it again, the jenkins is throwing an error 
`Warning foo.csproj - Unable to perform the get operation because it is writeable.`
One thing is clear that the project is unable to overwrite but I dont know why, so can please someone tell me why is this happening and how can I resolve it?
I checked all the files and folders are having read permission, which is an ideal case when the data is retrieved from TFS.

Answer (score 3):

Got the issue.
Someone has directly edited the files in the build box.